# Job "WrappedAPIView raised an exception. TypeError: view() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

Tags: python, django, apscheduler

I used apscheduler to run a job that calls the function UserViewSet() every 5 seconds.

views.py

```
    @api_view(['GET'])
    def UserViewSet(self):
       usersData=UserSerializer(UserDetail.objects.all().order_by('name'), many=True)
       return Response(usersData.data)
```

alerts_scheduler.py

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from .. import views
from rest_framework.request import Request

def start():
    scheduler=BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(views.UserViewSet, 'interval', seconds=5)
    scheduler.start()
```

But I keep getting "Job "WrappedAPIView raised an exception.TypeError: view() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'" everytime I run my application.
[image]

I am starting the scheduled job in apps.py as follows:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class AppbackendConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'AppBackend'

    def ready(self):
        from .app_scheduler import alerts_schedule
        alerts_schedule.start()
```

The project structure is something like this:

```
AppBackend

   app_scheduler
      __init__.py
      alerts_scheduler.py

   views.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django view takes a request and returns the response. The request can't be passed to APScheduler. So try scheduling a request to the view from APScheduler or write a separate function which makes a request to the view and schedule that to be run.

For example, if you want to perform any query or update any changes, dont make a call to the view, instead write a separate function as below.

```
def test():
     usersData=UserDetail.objects.all().order_by('name')
     #do anything with the queryset

def start():
    scheduler=BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(test, 'interval', seconds=5)
    scheduler.start()
```

also

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def UserViewSet(self):
```

should be :

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def UserViewSet(request):
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But even after I changed to def UserViewSet(request) in my views.py, I still see the same error.

Comment: Updated the answer. can you explain what are you trying to achieve here with the scheduler ?

Comment: I updated my answer with apps.py file, where I'm starting the scheduled job

Comment: in apps.py you are calling the scheduler instance. that's fine. but what is the ultimate result you are intending to get...please read the answer posted above. if you have any doubts, please comment